# Reading a binary file and using new line as a delimiter to create binary chunks

Tags: c#

I am totally out of my element when it comes to binary files. I need to read a binary file and break it into chunks using new line as the delimiter. I have tried googling this but its come up empty. Any help on this would be appreciated. It Has to be opened as binary file.

So i have a file of unknown encoding. I need to break out the file by chunks using `\n` newline as my delimiter. I am looking for a function that can break out this binary data with the new line as the delimiter.

Comment: What happens if one of the data chunks contains a newline character? This can happen, for example, if an integer has the value 10. A little more description of the file contents is in order. Otherwise, your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Data chunks are all numeric using newline as the delimiter for them. This is how the comm interface was given to me.

Comment: Does "Data chunks are all numeric" mean that they're numeric *strings* like "94732" and "3401", etc? And they're separated by newlines? Seems like what you have is a text file with one number per line. If that's the case, use a `StreamReader` to read line-by-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Helper Method

```
class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    //For a source containing N delimiters, returns exactly N+1 lists
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitOn(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        T delimiter)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (delimiter.Equals(item))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

## Usage

> I need to read a binary file and break it into chunks using new line as the delimiter.

```
var path = "binary-file.bin";
var delimiter = (byte)'\n';
var chunks = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
    .SplitOn(delimiter)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You are going to end up with garbage padding in the resulting lists depending on how the file was written.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Then you can add in a `.TakeWhile(chunk => chunk.Any())` line to the query, or something of that nature. Silly criticism - the answer is obviously providing the meat of the matter (`SplitOn` method).

Comment: Its not a silly criticism considering that if the data before the 'newline' is binary data, taking all bytes up to `\n` is totally different from taking all bytes up to `\r\n` or `0x0010` or any other encoding. You would have padding characters from the encoding or environment that would ruin your binary.

Comment: The OP gave no reason for me to assume that this is anything but some custom binary serialization format using `\n` as a delimiter between items. Unless the OP specifies otherwise...

Comment: The characters before '\n' are irreverent it truly is the only thing that matters. the carriage return is not even used as the contents of the line are parsed by position. I have tried using 'File.ReadAllLines' into a list but it for some reason it gets rid of some of the data. Anyway for some strange reason 'SplitOn' is not showing up in my intellisense.

Comment: @JBurlison I wrote it as an extension method. I'll update the answer so it's easier to do a drop-in replacement. :)

Comment: If this is a very large file, you're asking it to load all into memory at once with ReadAllBytes.  You might consider a foreach over the stream itself that returns just one chunk at a time so the caller has a chance to do something with the bytes and free up some memory before asking for the next one.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Unless the file is at least 100s of MBs, this is probably sufficient for the OP. The `SplitOn` method operators on an `IEnumerable<T>`, so a `IEnumerable<byte> ReadBytes(string path)` method in conjunction with that would work nicely for very large files.

Comment: @TimothyShields I did start with an "If".  I ran into that issue with a several GB file recently.  I thought the test department was being unreasonable, but the client decided he wanted those huge files supported.  How much large file support you need depends on your application and target use.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are inherently byte oriented. You can read a byte at a time into a buffer until you hit a newline, and then make a new buffer to read into.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if there is mixed binary and text data in your file and you don't know how to unpack it you're in trouble.

Second of all, what exactly do you mean by 'newline'? Were these newlines specifically written into the binary file as `0x10`? Or were you using some .Net interface that had a method like `WriteLine` on it? Or maybe you wrote some text into this file that contained newlines? In that case what encoding was used?

If you were handwriting these newlines as `0x10` you should be able to figure out how to split your binary stream on a single byte without too much difficulty.

If you used `WriteLine` or similar, that means it actually wrote `Environment.NewLine` not just `0x10`. In most cases on windows computers that means you are looking for `0x1310`. If you do not also trim the `0x13` off the front you will have an extra garbage byte at the end of every segment.

Now if you were writing strings with specific encoding that means that a newline is actually `0x10` or `0x00010` or `0x00000010` and `Environment.NewLine` is `0x1310` or `0x00130010` or `0x0000001300000010` so you should be splitting on those values instead. Oh and endian-ness would flip all these...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to verify what do you mean by new line - it could be: \n, \n\r or \r\n.
When you're sure of your notion of newline you should read binary file bytes and check if the bytes sequence contains byte equivalents of the characters I've mentioned above.

For example if you have single byte you may check it as follows:

```
byte singleByte = 1; //this value will be read from stream
if (singleByte == (byte) '\n')
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: new line is typically `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` (which is LF or CR or CRLF which is the values 10 or 13 or 13 10).
The value \n\r is almost never used.